# On 32-bit ARM Linux, how 2 GB RAM is addressed

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

Virtual address ranges 0xc0000000 (PAGE_OFFSET) .. 0xffffffff is mapped to physical memory.

If RAM is 1024 MB, then 0xc0000000 .. 0xffffffff is mapped to physical memory 0x00000000 to 0x40000000

How it is handled when we have 2GB of RAM on ARM based boards?

Answer (score 2):

Only pages in the low memory region (below `highmem_start_page()`) are directly-mapped in the kernel after `PAGE_OFFSET`. The rest can be dynamically mapped on demand using `kmap()` and `kunmap()` if a kernel mapping is needed, and should be unmapped when not needed to avoid running out of virtual address range.

Note that many use cases don't need a kernel memory mapping, as you can directly access the user address space of the running process.

Comment: Does the user space virtual address portion of 0 - 3GB is mapped to high mem?